# Microsoft PRISM: Using multiple regions in a WPF Menu control

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, prism

We are implementing a modular software with the help of PRISM and a huge number of modules. The framework contains the MainWindow Shell in which among other things the toolbar and menu is defined. Each module should be able to add its own toolbar and menu entries during runtime when the module is e.g. initialized. For this the region manager is used. For the toolbar it is working well but for the menu few problems occur:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--
        <Menu Grid.Row="0" IsMainMenu="True">
        <MenuItem Header="Test" />
        </Menu>
    -->
    <!--  Main Menu  -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">


        <ItemsControl Name="MainMenuRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static common:RegionNames.MainMenu}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl Name="AppMenuRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static common:RegionNames.AppMenu}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>


        <ItemsControl Name="HelpMenuRegion" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static common:RegionNames.HelpMenu}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>

    </StackPanel>
```

.....

The Region `RegionNames.MainMenu` is for the common entries like File, Edit, Veiw. The Region `RegionNames.AppMenu` is for the several modules to add its own menu. The Region `RegionNames.HelpMenu` is for the common entries Window and Help. The motivation for using the regions is to get an order for the menu entries. Each module creates its own view (user control) and view model for the menu in this way:

```
<Menu ItemsSource="{Binding MainMenuItems}" />
```

Furthermore for the Menu Items we are using a data template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Children, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{DynamicResource itemIcon}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSeparator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Separator />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Icon}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But this approach doesn't work. When trying to register the same view in two different regions like this:

```
IRegionViewRegistry regionViewRegistry = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionViewRegistry>();
regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.HelpMenu, typeof(MainMenu));
regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainMenu, typeof(MainMenu));
```

only the last region (MainMenu regions) will get the menu entries. The same behavior is in the case of two different views. It seems that the last one overwrites the first one.

I searched for suitable solutions but unfortunately till now I didn't find one for this use case. Hopefully I will find in this way a solution or another approach to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
IRegionViewRegistry regionViewRegistry = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionViewRegistry>();
regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.HelpMenu, typeof(MainMenu)); // registering same view with diferent region 
regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainMenu, typeof(MainMenu));
```

If I understand right then you define 3 regions (a placeholder where you can add custom user control in your case is menu item.)

1) RegionNames.HelpMenu

2) RegionNames. AppMenu

3) RegionNames.MainMenu

Now you need to create 3 custom User control and register them with the region.

```
 public partial class MainMenuSelection : UserControl 
    {
       public MainMenuSelection () 
       { 
         InitializeComponent();
       } 
    }
```

Similarly for app menu and help menu respectively

And then you can use like

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionViewRegistry>();
regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.HelpMenu,typeof(HelpMenuSelection));
regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainMenu, typeof(MainMenuSelection)); // You are registering view (mainmenuselection) with unique region placeholder(RegionNames.MainMenu)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. But I do that in this way you described

```
    IRegionViewRegistry regionViewRegistry = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionViewRegistry>();
    regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainMenu, typeof(MainMenu));
    regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.HelpMenu, typeof(HelpMenu));
```

and e.g. an UserControl for the Menu item

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXX.GUI.View.MainMenu"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

     <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding MainMenuItems}" /> 
</UserControl>
```

In my ViewModel the observable collection for MainMenuItems is created.
When I do that in this way the MenuItem is not top level rather then second Level and it is not possible to inject the Help Menu in to the Help Menu Region.